# Docker, django, node and staticfiles workflow

Tags: docker, build, automation, assets

I have a project where I use Django in the backend and Node.js in the frontend. I have doubts when using docker to install libraries for the frontend, run gulp scripts, webpack, transpile scss, javascript, copy images, fonts, etc. And then send them to S3.

Should I create a container specifically for that?
When do I install the libraries? When run the scripts and copy the files? When building the image (in Dockerfile) or when instantiating the container?

If I have to install libraries and copy files when building the image, where should I do it? When I put this in my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
```

It seems that it overwrites the folders and erases everything I've created during the installation and script executions.

I can not find real-world examples.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount host directory as data volume

```
docker run -d --name container_name -v /src/app:/app image_name
```